# SendMessageTimeout sometimes fails silently when sending to the correct handle

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, sendmessage

We're sending a Win32 message from one process (process01) to another  (process02).

```
Console.WriteLine(targetHandle); // 0x3072a

SendMessageTimeout(
    targetHandle, 
    WM_COPYDATA, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    ref cds, 
    SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL, 
    timeoutMs, 
    out result);
```

We've established that process01 is sending to the correct handle. Sometimes the message arrives at process02 and other times it doesn't arrive.

```
// SomeForm.cs
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    // Sometimes the message arrives here

    Console.WriteLine(m); // 0x3072a
}
```

When the message does not arrive at process02, there is no error message in process01. It simply fails silently.

What could be causing this? How can we further troubleshoot this? We have used Spy++ to search for and to listen to the messages to the receiving handle. Spy++ always finds the process by its handle. When the message does not show up in `SomeForm.WndProc`, it also does not show up in the Spy++ messages.

Comment: You are using a function that is designed to fail.  If you don't check its return value then you cannot find out that it did.  The timeoutMs value must be robust enough to deal with long pauses caused by a busy machine with not enough free RAM, don't force us to guess please.

Comment: can you have process 2 pass a message back to process 1?

Comment: @HansPassant The function's return value is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was permission elevation:

- the sending session was not elevated, and
- the receiving session was elevated (i.e. run as administrator).

Comment: @Shauna Luttin 
Is there any way to receive WM_COPYDATA when application is run as administrator